# What does this XSD restriction mean. Derived type with restriction just an attribute of the base type

Tags: xsd

There is a base type "Objectnummering-e" and a derived type "ObjectNummering-geoBAG".
The restriction on "ObjectNummering-geoBAG" mentions an attribute of the base type.

It is unclear to me what this does. To me the two types are identical. But are they?

```
<complexType name="ObjectNummering-geoBAG">
   <simpleContent>
      <restriction base="BG:ObjectNummering-e">
         <attribute ref="StUF:noValue"/>
       </restriction>
   </simpleContent>
</complexType>


<complexType name="ObjectNummering-e">
   <simpleContent>
      <extension base="BG:ObjectNummering">
         <attributeGroup ref="StUF:element"/>
      </extension>
   </simpleContent>
</complexType>


<simpleType name="ObjectNummering">
    <restriction base="string">
       <length value="16"/>
    </restriction>
</simpleType>

<attributeGroup name="element">
    <attribute ref="StUF:noValue"/>
    <attribute ref="StUF:exact"/>
 </attributeGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always, the only reliable way to answer a question like this is to go to the W3C specification. Your complex type is a 'complex type with simple content' so the relevant section is:

https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#declare-type, sub-section `Complex Type Definition with simple content Schema Component`

> > 3 if the type definition ·resolved· to by the ·actual value· of the base [attribute] is a complex type definition, the {attribute uses} of that type definition, unless the  alternative is chosen, in which case some members of that type definition's {attribute uses} may not be included, namely those whose {attribute declaration}'s {name} and {target namespace} are the same as one of the following:
> > 3.1 the {name} and {target namespace} of the {attribute declaration} of an attribute use in the set per clause 1 or clause 2 above;
> > 3.2 what would have been the {name} and {target namespace} of the {attribute declaration} of an attribute use in the set per clause 1 above but for the ·actual value· of the use [attribute] of the relevant  among the [children] of  being prohibited.

In plain English, it means that a complex type restriction must re-declare any attributes that it wants to retain - they are not automatically inherited. So derived type "ObjectNummering-geoBAG" only has 1 attribute, not 2.

Comment: Thanks, sometimes you just need that translation in plain English.